# How to force full-buffer videos on all platforms?

Tags: video, youtube, buffer, vimeo

On all the various platforms - e.g. Youtube, Vimeo, Wistia, they have an algorithm to control how much to buffer in advance (e.g. 3% ahead of current playtime). Is there a way in Chrome (e.g. by extension) to force the video to pre-buffer the ENTIRE video regardless of current playtime?